# Javascript: How to make an ISO string based on machine's local time

Tags: javascript

I need to make an ISO string like the on in the top of the following code snippet:

```
let somedate = "2021-01-01T00:00"

let anotherDate = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 16)
```

The point is, I know the Javascript implementation makes new Date() return a date based on the current time on the machine. But toISOString() always resets it to UTC. Is there any way I can make an ISO string like above, BASED on the local time, and NOT UTC? (In a somewhat easy way?)

The source of information regarding toISOString is from the following:
[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: The page you've linked to contains the polyfill, which you can easily adapt (just drop "UTC" everywhere).

Comment: Right, so you mean just copy it and make a local "Override"?

Comment: Just make a function like `toLocalISOString(date)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no such method to format your date. If I really needed such functionality I'd take a look at "Polyfill" section of the link you provided and created such method myself.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new `Prototype` function on the `Date` object

Using the `LocaleDateString` and `LocaleTimeString` to produce the `ISOString`

```js
let date = new Date();

Date.prototype.toLocaleISOString = function() {
  return `${this.toLocaleDateString().split('/').reverse().join('-')}T${this.toLocaleTimeString()}:${this.getMilliseconds()}`;
}

console.log(date.toLocaleISOString());
```

Comment: That's cool, however I solved it by using the Polyfilll method form the linked documentation.